# How to get summary for each panel in facet_wrap() in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

This is a generic question, Based on the facet_wraps() in ggplot we see in the link below for ex:
[ggplot by hadley/staticdocs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html)

Is there a way to get a summary() of the data from each panel of the facet_wrap or are we supposed to write a function get that sort of information ?

for example lets consider the plot from the above link:

```
p + geom_point(data = transform(cyl6, cyl = NULL), colour = "red") + facet_wrap(~ cyl)
```

How do we get say the % of red vs black dots from each panel ?

Comment: you mean % of red vs black dots isn't an option in facet wrap? I find that hard to believe. let me check the docs

Comment: it has an as.table optuion which states 
"If TRUE, the default, the facets are laid out like a table with highest values at the bottom-right. If FALSE, the facets are laid out like a plot with the highest value at the top-right"

Comment: as.table just controls the direction of the facets. If you want a summary of your data, you'd need to use `annotate` or something similar.

Comment: do you mean you want to add summary info to the graphs? are you trying to extract this info from the graphic itself? or are you just trying to calculate summary stats by the same groupings used for facet_wrap? It is not clear to me what you are trying to do

Comment: @JPC, I am trying to get summary stats from the graphic display of each panel

Comment: well my first thought would be, that if you have the graphic (g), you can access the data set using g$data, and you can see the facet variable with a similar g$facet and then you could use ddply from plyr library to calculate the stats for each panel

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a combination of the approaches above. Notably, it would be helpful to prespecify the colors you want ahead of time to make it easier to control the outputs and your summary statistics.

For example, I would specify your colors according to some rule like this (the code you have above doesn't seem to work):

```
my_mpg <- transform(mpg, dot_color = ifelse(hwy > 20, 'red','black'))
```

Then plot your data and specify the colors manually:

```
ggplot(my_mpg,aes(x=displ,hwy)) + geom_point(aes(color=dot_color)) + 
       facet_wrap(~cyl) + scale_color_manual(values=c('black','red'))
```

For aggregating statistics I think `data.table` provides the best interface:

```
library(data.table)
my_mpg <- as.data.table(my_mpg)
my_mpg[,list(percent_black = sum(dot_color=='black') / .N),by=cyl]

##    cyl percent_black
## 1:   4    0.04938272
## 2:   6    0.32911392
## 3:   8    0.84285714
## 4:   5    0.00000000
```